# git and Amazon s3

Tags: git, amazon-s3

Can I setup Git and Amazon S3? Any ideas on ways of doing it?

Comment: what do git and Amazon S3 have to do with each other?  Are you trying to combine them somehow?

Comment: it would be helpful to know HOW you want to set up git to work with S3 ... or the other way around. Could you be more specific?

Comment: jgit(java) supports pushing to s3 repository: http://blog.spearce.org/2008/07/using-jgit-to-publish-on-amazon-s3.html. There is also gits3(python) but it doesn't seem to be maintained any more: https://github.com/abdelhalim/gits3

Answer (score 6):

My preferred approach to using git with some remote storage (e.g. Jungle disk and the approach I use with Dropbox) is as follows:

1. Create a local working repo
2. Create a bare repo on the remotelysupplied storage (e.g. in a sync folder)
3. Set up the remote using file:// protocol
4. Push to the remote as needed

This means that you are not dependent on the remote connection for VC activity and traffic over the a possibly slow network is as efficient as possible.

If wanted you can add a post commit hook to push to the remote automatically.

(Sorry but I can't remember who to credit with this, it's not my idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replicate the code and repository, the easiest thing would be to use [Jungle Disk](https://www.jungledisk.com/) and create a sync folder.